# Get user properties using JavaScript for use in InfoPath - SP Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, infopath, html

I followed this blog - [Pass user information from SharePoint 2013 to InfoPath 2013](http://kitmenke.com/blog/2013/10/31/pass-user-information-from-sharepoint-2013-to-infopath-2013/)
It's a really good solution and works well but I want to expand it and get the users department and office location.

I thought it would just be a case of adding this at line 16

```
document.getElementById('userOffice').innerHTML = user.get_Office();
```

Then at line 22

```
url += '4[' + encodeURIComponent(user.get_office()) + ']';
```

Then at line 44

```
<span id="userOffice"></span>
```

But it doesn't seem to be the case. Can I do this or am I going about this the completely wrong way?

(sorry to send you off to a link - I would have pasted the whole code into this question but it wasn't having it for some reason)

Thanks
Jamie

Comment: have you found your answer? If so, please let us know or give us some feedback

Answer (score 0):

I am did something similar with REST to get the users department.

Then I set a link depending on the department he/she is in, onto my page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
    var loginName = "";
    var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;

    function GetCurrentUser() {

    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";

    var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };

    $.ajax({
      url : requestUri,
      contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
      headers : requestHeaders,
      success : onSuccessA,
      error : onErrorA
    });
    }

    function onSuccessA(data, request){

        // alert("Success One");
        // cutting of i:0#.w|
        var loginName = data.d.LoginName.split('|')[1];

        var repOne = "%5C";  
        var repTwo = "%2E";
        // alert("before replace: " + loginName);

        loginName = loginName.replace(/\\/g, repOne); // replace \ with %5C
        loginName = loginName.replace(/\./g, repTwo); // replace . with %2E

        // alert("after replace: " + loginName);

        GetCurrentUserDepartment(loginName); // call next function to get department. Pass the loginname into the function
    }

    function onErrorA(error) {

      alert(error);
    }

    GetCurrentUser();

    });

    function GetCurrentUserDepartment(loginNameAcc) {

    // alert("LoginName: " + loginNameAcc)
    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='Department')?@v=" + "'" + loginNameAcc + "'";

    var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };

    $.ajax({
      url : requestUri,
      method: "GET",
      headers : requestHeaders,
      success : onSuccessB,
      error : onErrorB
    });
    }

    function onSuccessB(data){

        var department = data.d.GetUserProfilePropertyFor;
        // alert("Team:" + department);
        var departmentArray = new Array(    
            "Information Technology",
            "Human Resources");

        var departmentArrayURL = new Array(     
            "information-technology-workspace",
            "human-resources-workspace");

        // set link to logged in users department
        switch(department){
            default:
                // alert("case default");
                break;
            case departmentArray[0]:
                // alert("case Information Technology");
                document.getElementById("teamuebersicht").innerHTML = "<a href='/teams/"+departmentArrayURL[0]+"'>Workspace</a>";
                break;
            case departmentArray[1]:
                // alert("case Human Resources");
                document.getElementById("teamuebersicht").innerHTML = "<a href='/teams/"+departmentArrayURL[1]+"'>Workspace</a>";
                break;
            }    
    }

    function onErrorB(jqxr,errorCode,errorThrown){
            alert("Error: " + jqxr.responseText)
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading it using the REST I used  the SharePoint OOTB control to get it on page load. I registered the namespace in masterpage like

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SPSWC" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

and to get a profile property, write some where in masterpage like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                var officeId = '<SPSWC:ProfilePropertyValue PropertyName="Office" ApplyFormatting="False" TitleMode="True" runat="server"/>';
                console.log(officeId);
            </script>
```

put your property name in place of "PropertyName" attribute value to get the value